# "angefangen bei" vs. "angefangen von"

Tags: difference

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen "angefangen bei" und "angefangen von? Ich habe dazu eine kleine Recherche im DWDS-Korpus durchgeführt:

> **angefangen bei**/ *51 Treffer*/: der Familie, den Eingaben Philipp Erasmus Reichs, ihrem Präsidenten, den Ernährungsgewohnheiten , meinen eigenen Kindern, der durchschnittlichen Länge der Schafwolle 
>   **angefangen von**/ *91 Treffer*/: Fütterungsschwierigkeiten, den Unterschieden der..., den Parteifunktionären, Prostitution, Maria, der Mutter des Erlösers, den geolog. Gegebenheiten, der sozialen Grundsicherung für alle, der Quecksilber-Mischlichtlampe

Bei den Beispielssätzen sehe ich im Allgemeinen keinen Unterschied, nur dass "angefangen von" knapp zweimal so häufig verwendet wird als "angefangen von"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wenn ich mir deine Beispiele durchlese und sie mir in einem weiteren Kontext vorstelle, kommt mir immer mehr der Verdacht, dass "angefangen von" eigentlich so gut wie nie eine gute Formulierung ist.

> Angefangen **von** Maria, der Mutter des Erlösers, finden sich im neuen Testament viele Gestalten mit außergewöhnlichen Eigenschaften.
>
> Angefangen **von** der sozialen Grundsicherung gibt es zahlreiche Probleme, die die Politik lösen muss, will sie die Demokratie sichern.
>
> Angefangen **von** Prostitution  bis hin zu Menschenhandel präsentiert uns der Balkan auch heute noch ein fröhliches Sammelsurium menschlicher Abgründe.
>
> Angefangen **von** der Quecksilber-Mischlichtlampe (und mit der Natriumdampflampe noch lange nicht schließend) bietet die Leuchtmittelindustrie heute Lösungen für Beleuchtungszwecke jeder Art.

All diese Satzanfänge klingen für mich unbeholfen. Formuliert man sie um mit "angefangen bei" werden Satzstücke draus, die man getrost auch in gedruckten Texten verwenden kann.

> Angefangen **bei** Maria, der Mutter des Erlösers, finden sich im neuen Testament viele Gestalten mit außergewöhnlichen Eigenschaften.
>
> Angefangen **bei** der sozialen Grundsicherung gibt es zahlreiche Probleme, die die Politik lösen muss, will sie die Demokratie sichern.
>
> Angefangen **bei** Prostitution bis hin zu Menschenhandel präsentiert uns der Balkan auch heute noch ein fröhliches Sammelsurium menschlicher Abgründe.
>
> Angefangen **bei** der Quecksilber-Mischlichtlampe (und mit der Natriumdampflampe noch lange nicht schließend) bietet die Leuchtmittelindustrie heute Lösungen für Beleuchtungszwecke jeder Art.

Könnte es sein, dass deine vielen Funde mit "angefangen von" aus mündlichen Texten stammen oder aus Texten, die von Leuten mit mangelndem Sprach- und Stilgefühle geschrieben wurden?

**Mein Fazit soweit:**

Mir scheint, *angefangen von* ist eine zwar verbreitete, aber unsaubere Formulierung, vielleicht entstanden aus der Verwechslung mit ***ausgehend von***.

Besser sagt man *angefangen bei* oder ***angefangen mit***.

> Angefangen mit Donald Trump können einem die Amerikaner in letzter Zeit ganz schön auf die Nerven gehen.

Comment: Die Beispiele hören sich für mich nicht unbeholfen, sondern *falsch* an - Oder zumindest unnötig "doppelt gemoppelt", da sowohl *angefangen* als auch *von* einen Ausgangspunkt markieren.

Answer (score 4):

Die Ergebnisse Deiner Recherche über den DWDS-Korpus entsprechen ziemlich genau den Ergebnissen meiner entsprechenden [Google-Books-Ngram-Viewer-Recherche](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=angefangen%20bei%2C%20angefangen%20mit%2C%20angefangen%20von&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cangefangen%20bei%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cangefangen%20mit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cangefangen%20von%3B%2Cc0): "angefangen von" wird in der Schriftsprache knapp zweimal so häufig verwendet wie "angefangen bei".

Zoomt man in die Treffer hinein, stellt man weitgehend austauschbare Verwendung fest. Einen Unterschied findet man nur selten und nur in einem Detail:

Im Gegensatz zu "angefangen bei" spannt "angefangen von" in **allen** von mir gesichteten Treffern eine "Spanne" auf: "angefangen von ... (über ...) bis (hin) zu ...". Bei "angefangen bei" finden sich dagegen vereinzelt Treffer ohne so eine "Spanne".

Das entspricht voll und ganz meinem Sprachgefühl.

Answer (score 2):

Zunächst ein eher langweiliger Unterscheid:

(1) Angefangen von links, wird der Makler die gesamte Häuserreihe inspizieren.

(2) #Angefangen bei links, wird der Makler die gesamte Häuserreihe inspizieren.

Evtl. besser wäre in (1): ‚Von links anfangend...‘. Außerdem ist 'Angefangen *mit* links...' ebenso falsch  wie (2).

Überdies gibt es einen klaren Unterschied zwischen ‚von‘ und ‚bei‘. Insbesondere kann man sagen ‚von **A** bis **B**‘, aber nicht ‚bei **A** bis **B**‘. Deshalb läßt sich vermuten, daß ‚angefangen bei‘ nur den Anfangspunkt nennt, während ‚angefangen von‘ dann mit ‚über‘ und ‚bis zu‘ zum Zielpunkt fortgeführt werden kann (oder muß). Ein Beispiel mag es verdeutlichen.

Das Luxushotel wird morgen vom Inhaber besucht.  …

(3) Angefangen bei der Eingangshalle, wird er das gesamte Hotel inspizieren.

(4) Angefangen von den Besenkammern, über die Gästezimmer, und bis zum großen Ballsaal, wird er das gesamte Hotel inspizieren.

In (3) wird offengelassen, wo der Inhaber die Inspektion fortsetzt: in den Räumen, die an die Eingangshallen angrenzen, oder vielleicht im Speisesaal? In (4) ist eine klare Reihenfolge zu erkennen: er fängt bei den kleinsten Zimmern an und macht dann mit den größeren weiter. Die Inspektion verläuft also *von* den kleinsten Zimmern (über die mittleren) und *bis* zu den großen.

Das würde dann auch erklären, warum die Beispiele von Christian Geiselmann nicht natürlich klingen: weil von keiner Reihenfolge die Rede ist. (Das Beispiel mit ‚von Prostitution bis hin zu Menschenhandel‘ finde ich dementsprechend auch am natürlichsten.)

Vielleicht läßt sich die Situation noch verdeutlichen, wenn wir ‚anfangen‘ selbst anschauen, und es im Hauptsatz verwenden.

Einbrecher Ede hat vor, die Leute in der Blümchensiedlung zu bestehlen. Er will jedem Haushalt einen Topf, eine Gießkanne, und drei Eier stehlen. Damit es nicht gleich auffällt, will er aber nicht alles auf einmal stehlen. Leo Langfinger fragt Ede:

LL: Womit wirst Du denn anfangen?
EE: Ich fange **mit** den Gießkannen an.

LL: Wo wirst Du zuerst einbrechen?
EE: Ich fange **bei** den Meiers an.

LL: In welcher Reihenfolge willst Du vorgehen?
EE: Ich fange **von** der Südseite der Siedlung (her) an.

Im letzten Satz kann weder ‚mit‘ noch ‚bei‘ verwendet werden. Umgekehrt kann man ‚von‘ weder im ersten noch im zweiten Satz verwenden. Ggf. sind ‚mit‘ und ‚bei‘ austauschbar; allerdings hat Leo ‚womit?‘ und ‚wo?‘ gefragt. Dementsprechend sind ‚mit‘ und ‚bei‘ die besseren Antworten. (Interessant, daß das Englische hier nur ein Wort kennt: ‚with‘.)

Fazit: *anfangen* *mit*, *bei*, und *von* sind alle drei möglich. Sie beantworten aber unterschiedliche Fragen.

Answer (score 0):

„Angefangen von“ ist umgangssprachlich und sollte in gedruckten Texten nicht verwendet werden. Dass es dennoch häufig eingesetzt wird, beweist nicht das Gegenteil (siehe häufige Fehler wie "übrigends", "in keinster Weise" etc.).

Sprachlich korrekt ist entweder **"angefangen bei ... über ... bis"** oder
**"Von ... über ... bis"**

Gänzlich falsch sind die Beistriche in dem oben angeführten Beispiel:
Angefangen von den Besenkammern, über die Gästezimmer, und bis zum großen Ballsaal, wird er das gesamte Hotel inspizieren.